Error When Importing PyAutoGUI in Archlinux
I'm having issues importing pyautogui after installing it.
Output of hostnamectl:
 Static hostname: archlinux
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop 
      Machine ID: feee6bbdd3b94cdd9de25a09801e7fb8
         Boot ID: 463321eb08054209ad65b5b793c8727f
Operating System: Arch Linux                      
          Kernel: Linux 6.11.5-arch1-1
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: HP
  Hardware Model: HP Laptop 15-bs2xx
Firmware Version: F.40
   Firmware Date: Wed 2018-05-16
    Firmware Age: 6y 5month 1w 5d  

Here is the error I'm getting when trying to import the pyautogui module:
>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/curtis/Documents/python_projects/test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/curtis/Documents/python_projects/test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/curtis/Documents/python_projects/test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/curtis/Documents/python_projects/test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/home/curtis/Documents/python_projects/test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified\n'


I'm unsure on where to start with this error. So any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Please [edit] your question and add details how exactly you run your program. I don't know what pyautogui is supposed to do, but apparently it has problems connecting to an X server (or similar) display :0. Are you running the program from a graphical desktop environment´? Using a terminal window? A program starter? ...

Try running it with root permission.

Don't throw elevated access around without a good reason. Why would running this as root help? Why should elevated access be needed?
